# P/Invoke in ASP.NET (Reading/writing text file from dll)

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, pinvoke

I have a `C++ Win32` program in which I am writing and reading a text file. This C++ program generates a dll and I am referencing this dll in my ASP.NET web application.
Using P/Invoke, I am calling methods to read and write file from this dll.

The dll is working fine when I tested this out with P/invoke in WPF application.
The reference dll is in the `bin/Debug` folder for this WPF app, and the write method in dll when called generates a text file in the same folder.
Further, `from the same folder`, I can use the dll's read method to read the text file.

However, when I call the Dll methods from my ASP.NET web app, the genearted file goes to some other directory (most probably because the dll is loaded somewhere else to execute) and I am not able to locate where this generated file goes (without any error)

Similar to desktop application, is there some way that the fie will be written in bin folder itself, so that I can read from the bin folder itself?

Example code:
**.cpp file**

```
extern "C" D_API int Write1()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
    return 1;
}

extern "C" D_API char* Read1()
{
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("test.txt");
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) 
        {
        myReadFile >> output;       
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

**C# .aspx.cs**

```
[DllImport("Testing1.dll", EntryPoint = "fnTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int Write1();


        [DllImport("Testing1.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern StringBuilder Read1();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using relative paths, the file will be relative to the working directory of the process at the point at which you call into the native code. This is a rather brittle arrangement as you have discovered.

I would solve the problem by adding an extra string parameter to the native code that specifies the full path of the file to use. You can generate this easily enough from your managed code I am sure.

**Native code**

```
extern "C" D_API int WriteTest(char *filename)
{
    ....
    myfile.open(filename);
    ....
}
```

**Managed code**

```
[DllImport("Testing1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int WriteTest();
```

---

The other point to make is that your function to read data is incorrect. It attempts to return a stack allocated buffer. You need to allocate a buffer in the managed code and then pass that to the native code. Perhaps something like this:

```
extern "C" D_API int ReadTest(char *filename, char* buffer, int len)
{
     //read no more than len characters from filename into buffer
}
```

And on the managed side:

```
[DllImport("Testing1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ReadTest(string filename, StringBuilder buffer, int len);
....
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(100);
int retval = ReadTest(FullySpecifiedFileName, buffer, buffer.Capacity);
```

Comment: ..and using the default working directory can also have permission problems - e.g. you can end up with a directory where the IIS process cannot write.

Comment: @MMo True that, but the fact that it's not where you want the file to be is really the killer.

Comment: Sure - I was just adding one more reason why it is best to avoid blidly using the current working directory.

Comment: @David Heffernan: So, this means I should pass the full path of the file (default `bin` folder  of the website in this case), ..WebSite1/bin/test.txt and then use the same path for reading the file as well. Seams fine to me but I wanted to clarify one thing if passing the path of the file on every method call in Dll is ideal?

Comment: Passing the full path of the file to the DLL every call would be fine. If you are worried about the overhead of that then the fact that you are opening and closing a file every time you call should make the parameter passing overhead trivial in comparison.