# Issue in Reading/Writing files through P/Invoke in ASP.NET bin folder

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, file-io, pinvoke

I have been trying to write and read files through P/Invoke via my ASP.NET website. I am facing a problem as to where the files are written/read when doing this through `dlls` in a website. I have tried to explain the problem with the below example:

**.cpp file (containing a read and write function)**

```
extern "C" TEST_API int fnTest(char* fileDir)
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (strcat(fileDir, "test.txt"));
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
}

extern "C" TEST_API char* fnTest1(char* fileDir)
{
ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open(strcat(fileDir, "test1.txt"));
char output[100];
if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
    myReadFile >> output;
return output;
}
```

**Post build event of website to copy the dll's from above C++ project to website's `bin` folder**

**Default.aspx.cs - C#**
**Dll functions**

```
public static class Functions(){
DllImport[("Test1.dll", EntryPoint="fnTest", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi]
public static extern int fnTest(string dir);

DllImport[("Test1.dll", EntryPoint="fnTest1", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi]
public static extern StringBuilder fnTest1(string dir);
}
```

**Page_Load event**

```
string direc = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "bin\\";
string txt1 = Functions.fnTest(direc).ToString(); //failing here - keeps on loading the page forever
string txt2 = Functions.fnTest(direc).ToString(); //failing here - keeps on loading the page forever
```

If I try the same Page_Load code in a desktop application with `direc` being set as current directory of the project output, everything works fine. It's only that the directories where the files are to be written or read are kind of messed in case of web site and I am not really able to figure out how to correct this and get it working. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already asked the exact same question. And the answer is just the same. Pass the full path to the filename to your native code. And my answer at your previous question even solved the error in the way you return the string.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Passing the full path this time as written above in the post, and the error has changed now. So, wrote a new post for what I tried and something's still wrong

Comment: You didn't pass the full path to the file. You just passed the dir. And so you can't do `strcat` since that adds to the end of `fileDir` and you can't write to that memory since its owned by the pinvoke marshaller. And you didn't take any notice of the second half of my answer at the previous question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have a number of the same problems as you have in the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313144/p-invoke-in-asp-net-reading-writing-text-file-from-dll).

This time round your biggest problem is here:

```
strcat(fileDir, "test.txt")
```

You can't modify `fileDir` since it is owned by the pinvoke marshaller. Instead of passing the directory to your native code, pass the full path to the file. Use `Path.Combine` in your managed code to create that, and pass it to the native code.

```
extern "C" TEST_API int fnTest(char* filename)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename);
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
}
```

and in managed code

```
string filename = Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin", "test.txt");
string txt1 = Functions.fnTest(filename).ToString();
```

---

In a comment you explain that you need to concatenate strings in the native code. You will need to create a native string to do that because you are not allowed to write to `fileDir`. Something like this:

```
string fileName = string(fileDir) + "test.txt";
myfile.open(fileName.c_str());
```

---

But you still need to fix `fnTest1` which reads the file. My answer at your other question tells you how to do that.

Comment: @DavidHefferman: Turns out that this concatenation operation has to be performed somehow in C++ program only. The name of the text files are not known in C# program and are only known in the C++ program which cannot be changed. The whole program is quite different from the post, but I chose to write an example of the problem I am facing. Is there any solution to the method in which I can use this `concatenatination` with the fileDir for all the txt files I have in C++?

Comment: As part of trying to figure out the problem, I did try the same concatenation by passing the `Project output` directory of a Windows forms application and using the above all to read and write files and it was working fine. I wonder why the concatenation operations could be performed in that case, and not in case of a website?

Comment: My latest update tells you how to concatenate a string in C++.