# C++ dll fails to write to file when linked to asp.net c# application

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, dll

I have a C++ dll.  I would like to have it write to a log file on the server.  When I link it to a console application it writes to the file just fine.  When I link it to the asp.net application the file I/O fails.  Not really sure what I am missing.

This is the C++ dll code that works fine when linked with console app.

```
char* LogHelper()
{
  char* buff = new char[500];

  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("testlog.txt",ios::out);
  if(myfile.is_open())
    strcpy(buff,"we made it");
  else
    strcpy(buff,"fail, fail, fail..........");


  return buff;
}
```

Here is the C# code behind that calls it

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [DllImport("C:\\Dev\\ChatLib\\Debug\\ChatLib.dll")]
    public static extern string dllStartMain();

    protected void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      t1.Text = dllStartMain();
    }
}
```

Seems like it should be pretty simple.  Why does the dll work when linked to a console app but not a web app?  I know it executes the dll because it returns the "fail, fail, fail.........." string.

Any help or suggestions of articles to read on the subject would be tremendously appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there really a reason you need to use C++ in a web application? Also consider that ASP.NET has very locked down permissions for a reason. Finally... why not just use the built in .NET logging?

Comment: possible duplicate of [P/Invoke in ASP.NET (Reading/writing text file from dll)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313144/p-invoke-in-asp-net-reading-writing-text-file-from-dll)

Comment: I am using legacy C++ code.  Don't really want to rewrite it.  The dll needs to be able to write to log file.

Comment: I would highly suggest taking a look at what it's doing, and if that functionality is implemented by the framework.

Comment: You open the file in C++, but you never close it. That's a problem.

Comment: Standard C++ streams have little to no way of getting error information (even though I could bet it's `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` anyway). Check the ASP.Net user has write access to the file.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: C++ streams are RRIF, the file is closed when the stream goes out of scope (when the function returns).

Answer (score 0):

```
extern "C" __declspec char* LogMain();
{
    //Put your code here..
    //return the char*.
}

[DllImport("ChatLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern StringBuilder LogMain();
```

OR

```
public static class Importer
{

    [DllImport("ChatLib.dll", EntryPoint = "LogMain", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public static extern string LogMain();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    string s = Importer.LogMain();
}
```

OR just use the unsafe keyword:

```
//Import function just like above
unsafe
{
    char* t = Importer.LogMain();
    string s = new string(t);
}
```